# Best practice to map a class using annotations on another class in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

The problem that I'm facing is that I'm trying to separate the persistence from the logic of my application. So what I'm trying to accomplish is to create a new class in another package where I would put the annotations to persist the data.

For example, I have a class `Type` inside the package `teste.1`, the class has the following attributes:

```
public class Type {
    public static final int LOGIC = 0;
    public static final int REAL = 1;
    public static final int STRING = 2;
    private String name;
    private int type;
    private String description;
}
```

I'd like to create another class in a different package that would allow me to implement the annotations without modifying the `Type` class. What would be the best practice to map this class without modifying the first class?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use annotation ? If you wish to decouple POJO and hibernate mapping, why don't you use hbm xml file for the mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not a good practice to duplicate classes and mapping to transit data within a application : memory and cpu overhead. 
But anyway you can make 2 classes and automapping them with a tool like dozer : http://dozer.sourceforge.net/.
If they have the same properties name it works out of the box.